# Eliminate duplicates from table when applying LOWER() MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here is my problem: I want to normalize the field `name` from my table. I have a `tag` table which contains all the tags from my recipes.
Here is its structure:

```
tag: tag_id(pk), name(unique)
recipe_tag: tag_id(fk), recipe_id(fk) (composite pk)
```

Even though the "name" column is unique, I have fields like this: "avocat", "avocat ", etc.

What I want to do is trim all the whitespaces and lowercase the field.
I tried `UPDATE SET name = TRIM(LOWER(name))` but I get duplicate errors, considering the field should be unique.

How can I bypass that, while updating all the `tag_id` reference in my `recipe_tag` table, to the unique tag?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a case-sensitive collation?

Comment: Add a column to `tag`. Fill it with normalized tag `id `value. Check that there exist a row where original value and normalized one are equal, if not then add row with such values for all such normalized tags. Update the table `recipe_tag` and replace FK with FK of normalized `name` (use 2 copies of `tag` table). Add according CHECK constraint. Remove rows with wrong tags. Remove column.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I get the same problem when I try to insert new rosw in my duplicated table using the following query: ```INSERT INTO tag_duplicate (name, normalized)
SELECT normalized, normalized
FROM tag_duplicate
WHERE (name != normalized)```